# Return key for JS Map constructor with value

Tags: javascript

I'm running into difficulty retrieving keys from a JS Map constructor.

Say you have the code below:

```
var myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('AK', 'Alaska');
myMap.set('CO', 'Colorado');

console.log(myMap.get('CO'))
```

This console.logs `'Colorado'`. I'm trying to figure out how I can do the opposite and return the key (`'CO'`) using the value (`'Colorado'`).

In a perfect world I could just do `myMap.get('Colorado')` to return `'CO'` but this does not work.

Comment: *In a perfect world I could just do `myMap.get('Colorado')` to return 'CO' but this does not work.* It's actually good, that this doesn't work, imagine having a key and a value from two different entries with the same value.

Comment: What's wrong with using two maps then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map is best used when you have **unique** keys mapping to a value.

Assuming that key-value pairs are **distinct** in your use case, we can write a helper to find key using value.

```
function getKey(map, value) {
   var found = Array.from(map.keys())
      .find((key) => map.get(key) === value);
   return found[0]; // returning undefined is just fine. 
}
```

Comment: Use find instead of filter, otherwise you'll go on with lookup even when the corresponding key is already found.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the map to be indexed with the abbreviations? If not, you can just set data inside of it the other way:

```
myMap.set('Alaska', 'AK');
```

Otherwise, you're gonna need to loop through the entries of your map:

```
let entry;
for (entry of myMap.entries()) {
    if (entry === 'CO') {
        break;
    }
}
```